# Unable to retrieve value from a map even though the key is correct

Tags: apex, map, get

[image]

I have a map and have pushed a value into it, but when using get map, the result returns null. After debugging, I found that the key is correct. What could be the reason? Can someone help me?

This is my result debug

11:52:49:029 USER_DEBUG [82]|DEBUG|KEY WEB MANH: Onboard/During FlightOthers
=> Key put into map

11:52:49:069 USER_DEBUG [107]|DEBUG|lstCode size: 1

11:52:49:069 USER_DEBUG [108]|DEBUG|mapKeyMappingAssignTo keySet: {Onboard/During FlightOthers}
=> Result debug map keySet

11:52:49:069 USER_DEBUG [111]|DEBUG|code.CAPA_Key_Assign_Case_Form__c: Onboard/During flightOthers
=> Key get

11:52:49:069 USER_DEBUG [113]|DEBUG|c: null
=> Result

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key you put into the map: `Onboard/During FlightOthers` (uppercase "F")
The key you use to get the value from the map: `Onboard/During flightOthers` (lowercase "f")
Keys are case-sensitive, so they are not the same string. It's just the SOQL that ignore the case of string.

To fix this issue you should normalize your keys transforming them to lowercase (or uppercase) when using them:

```java
String caseKey = (c.Category__c + c.Sub_Category__c + c.Location__c).replace('null', '');
mapKeyMappingAssignTo.put(caseKey.toLowerCase(), c);
...
mapKeyMappingAssignTo.get(code.CAPA_Key_Assign_Case_From__c.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: I really didn't see that letter F, thank you.